# MissingSecret [MissingSecretError]: Please define a `secret` in production

Tags: next.js, vercel, next-auth

According to the docs https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#secret ,
adding a **NEXTAUTH_SECRET** as an environment variable, you don't have to define this option.

But in vercel production I still get,

```
2022-03-24T10:37:19.571Z    710a4b4b-24d3-4fb4-b991-9eb44179efc8    ERROR   [next-auth][error][NO_SECRET] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#no_secret Please define a `secret` in production. MissingSecret [MissingSecretError]: Please define a `secret` in production.
    at assertConfig (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/assert.js:24:14)
    at NextAuthHandler (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:34:52)
    at NextAuthNextHandler (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:16:51)
    at /var/task/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:52:38
    at Object.apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:182:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async NextNodeServer.runApi (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:386:9)
    at async Object.fn (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:488:37)
    at async Router.execute (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:228:32)
    at async NextNodeServer.run (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:600:29) {
  code: 'NO_SECRET'
}
```

env is set as `NEXTAUTH_SECRET=MYSECRETSNAPBOOK`

**Code:**

```
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.user.username = session.user.name
        .split(' ')
        .join('')
        .toLocaleLowerCase()

      session.user.uid = token.sub

      return session
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the Fix,

1. In .env file (or your vercel env) add `NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET=anything` (Make sure you have **NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET** name as it is)
2. Add a secret option in [...nextauth].js

`providers: [//Your providers],`

`secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET`

3. Make sure you don't use 7beta version. Up or Downgrade it to 4.1.2 (`npm i next-auth@4.1.2`)

Comment: Wouldn't this create a security flaw/breach?

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser

Comment: downgrade to 4.1.2 work for me 

Comment: @Muutu A. NO! `[...nextauth]` file is not running on the browser but on the server

Comment: you should not use PUBLIC for a secret!

Answer (score 0):

A `secret` is needed as written in `next-auth.js.org` here :

- https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#secret.
  In my case, only `process.env.SECRET` has worked in Prod. Make sure to create a strong secret. I advise you this tool from Vercel :
- https://generate-secret.vercel.app/32

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const options = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
    })
  ],
  secret: process.env.SECRET // To be added
};

const authHandler: NextApiHandler = (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options);

export default authHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `NEXT_PUBLIC` to `NEXTAUTH_URL` from .env file, might be solved this issue for next-auth version 4.24.5

```
   providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_GG_ID}`,
            clientSecret: `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET}`,
        }),
        // ...add more proviers here
    ]
```