# Receiving a 404 on Production with Next-auth on Next JS 13

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13

It is a next.js13 application that uses next-auth for authentication. It is currently set up with only Azure AD as provider.

In development everything works fine, but in production, when I just enter the Landingpage a got a 404 back.

When I try to open another page like https://mySite/dashboard, I got the following Server Error:

```
\[next-auth\]\[error\]\[NO_SECRET\]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#no_secret Please define a `secret` in production. MissingSecret \[MissingSecretError\]: Please define a `secret` in production.
at assertConfig (/datahub-ui/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/assert.js:42:12)
at NextAuthHandler (/datahub-ui/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:70:52)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async NextAuthNextHandler (/datahub-ui/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:24:19)
at async auth (/datahub-ui/.next/server/pages/api/auth/\[...nextauth\].js:37:12)
at async Object.apiResolver (/datahub-ui/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:363:9)
at async NextNodeServer.runApi (/datahub-ui/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:474:9)
at async Object.fn (/datahub-ui/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:736:37)
at async Router.execute (/datahub-ui/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:252:36)
at async NextNodeServer.run (/datahub-ui/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:383:29) {
code: 'NO_SECRET'
}
```

**Code:**
[...nextauth].ts

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import AzureADProvider from 'next-auth/providers/azure-ad'
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export default async function auth(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
const providers = \[
AzureADProvider({
clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
tenantId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
}),
\]
return await NextAuth(req, res, {
providers,
secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
})
}
```

.env.production

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID='..................-9cea-a456aa4a38f4'
NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID='..................-adec-c9cc85f02498'
NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET='.............................bR7'
NEXTAUTH_SECRET='1...........................................3cf'
NEXTAUTH_URL='https://mySite'
```

I already check out some related Issues (or at least, I think they are related) :

- https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/3245
- [MissingSecret [MissingSecretError]: Please define a `secret` in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71600978/missingsecret-missingsecreterror-please-define-a-secret-in-production)

Any ideas how I can find the Issue?

Answer (score 0):

What's the need of having to default export an auth() handler?

According to the documentation, you do not need to export a custom handler like you did.

All you need is have something like this in the [...nextauth].tsx file.

```
const providers = [
  AzureADProvider({
    clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
    tenantId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
  }),
];

export default NextAuth({ providers })
```

And that should work. If you still face any issues with it, refer to the [new NextAuth.js documentation](https://authjs.dev/getting-started/oauth-tutorial) or you can check out this article that explained everything with steps and code examples: [How to implement Google login and protected routes using NextAuth](https://awacreates.com/blog/how-to-implement-google-login-and-protected-routes-using-nextauth)

I hope this helps.